# How to generate a random float number in Objective-C with min and max?

Tags: objective-c

> **Possible Duplicates:**
>   [Generating Random Numbers in Objective-C](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/160890/generating-random-numbers-in-objective-c)
>   [What's the most optimal way to get a random floatingpoint number between floatA and floatB?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/887240/whats-the-most-optimal-way-to-get-a-random-floatingpoint-number-between-floata-a)

Hi,

I want to generate a random float number like

```
float scale = randFloat(0.5f, 2.0f);
```

How do I do this in objective-c?

Comment: This answer does not help me!

Comment: perhaps you could explain why....

Comment: Maybe because the answer is returning an int.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is how you generate them :

```
// Get random value between 0 and 99
int x = arc4random() % 100;

// Get random number between 500 and 1000
int y =  (arc4random() % 501) + 500);
```

You can easily extend this for any range you need.

Hope that helps.

Answer (score 1):

Generate two random integers and divide one by the other. With some manipulation you can introduce a range.

Also, depending on the required resolution you could simply generate a single random integer and divide it by a fixed integer to get your float.  For example, generate a random number between 0 and 100,000 and divide it by 100,000. You can offset and shift the result around to get the range you need.